# Найти координаты точек внутри пирамидальной области

Tags: математика, геометрия, matlab, octave

> Дан массив точек в пространстве. Обозначим точку из него как *P*. Из некоторой точки *C* вдоль оси *OZ* проведена четырехугольная пирамида такая, что ребра ее основания параллельны осям *OX* и *OY*, а сам четырехугольник является прямоугольником. Также известен угол между *OZ* и гранями пирамиды (пусть *phi1* - угол с гранью, основание которой параллельно *OX*, а *phi2* - угол с гранью, основание которой параллельно *OY*). Задача состоит в том, чтобы из всех *P* заданного массива отобрать те точки, которые лежат внутри заданной пирамиды.

При чем, пирамида имеет бесконечную высоту, поэтому при попытке решить данный вопрос я пыталась ориентироваться именно на углы отклонения от высоты, которая и лежит на *OZ*.

Моя идея была такова:

```
1) Пусть P = (Px, Py, Pz), C = (cx, cy, cz)
2) Pxz = (Px-cx, Py-cy), Pyz = (Py-cy, Py-cy)
3) Ox = (cx+1,cy,cz), Oy = (cx,cy+1,cz), Oz = (cx,cy,cz+1)
4) Далее ищем угол между Pxz и Oz (alpha) и угол между Pyz и Oz (beta)
5) Если |alpha|<=phi1 и |beta|<=phi2, то точка P нам подходит, иначе смотрим следующую точку.
```

Однако, когда я делала это в Matlab, результат выдавался неверным.
На изображении показана общая картина. Голубая, малиновая и зеленая линии - это система координат, относительно которой строится пирамида. Синяя линия - пространственный эллипс, точки которого - это заданный массив.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть алгоритм Джарвиса, его можно переложить в пространство, или же использовать произведение векторов

Comment: вроде всё выглядит правильно... код и примеры данных проходящих/непроходящих проверку в студию...

Comment: @Neuro, ради интееса, при чём тут вообще алгоритм Джарвиса?

Comment: Вам нужно построить трехмерную оболочку, значит все точки , лежащие внутри пирамиды, будут точками, которые не вошли в выпуклую оболочку, если я правильно понял задачу

Comment: ещё, формально, алгоритм не проверяет то что точка находится ниже пирамиды, а не с обратной стороны... если с математикой проблем нет, то я бы поставил на это...

Comment: @Neuro, «Задача состоит в том, чтобы из всех P заданного массива отобрать те точки, которые лежат внутри заданной пирамиды.»... в вопросе вроде нет ни слова про оболочку... или может я чего-то не замечаю...

Comment: эммм.... может я ошибаюсь, но разве не достаточно проверить условия ``` |Px - Cx| < |Pz - Cz|*tg(phi1) ; |Py - Cy| < |Pz - Cz| *tg(phi2)``` ну, и то, что пирамида и точка по одну сторону точки С, а не по разные?

Comment: "грани ее основания" - дальше не читал

Comment: есть множество точек, образующих оболочку, значит она является максимальной, значит алгоритм джарвиса, построивший  максимальную оболочку совпадет с пирамидой, соответственно :: допустим у нас есть точка O для нее лучшей является точка W, значит она принадлежит P{}, но если найдется такая точка X, которая оптимальнее точки W, то в множестве X принадлежит P{}, а W не принадлежит, противоречие, значит алгоритм джарвиса найдет оптимальные точки

Comment: @Igor, да, думаю об одном, пишу о другом)

Comment: Как можно проверить, что точка и пирамида находятся по одну сторону от C?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов, я попробовала пока без проверки, что точка и пирамида по одну сторону от С лежат, но даже так выделялись не все нужные точки (я исключаю те, которые выходят за границу). Мой массив точек - это точки эллипса в пространстве, т.е. нужно выделить дугу, которая лежит внутри пирамиды. Однако результат выходит какой-то смещенный. Возможно, я что-то делаю не так.

Comment: @Юрий Козлов Пардон, сразу не углядел ваш комментарий среди выпуклых оболочек и дал по сути тот же ответ.

Comment: @Fire13nyu, да просто `Pz<Cz`... но у Юрия Козловлова всё равно более здравая идея...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, я ею и решила воспользоваться) Но возникла проблема с поворотами системы координат, о которых я написала ниже в комментариях.

Comment: MBo не страшно. К тому же, у Вас расписано более тщательно и аккуратно :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задаётся пирамида, конечно, альтернативненько....

Подразумеваем, что P - верхняя точка пирамиды.

Сечение пирамиды плоскостью `z = P.Z`  является прямоугольником с полуразмерами

```
hw = (P.Z - C.Z) * tan(phi1)
hh = (P.Z - C.Z) * tan(phi2)
```

Остаётся проверить, что

```
abs(P.X - C.X) <= hw  && abs(P.Y - C.Y) <= hh
```

Comment: Можете тогда помочь со следующим вопросом? Моя система координат для пирамиды повернута относительно привычной. Что тогда нужно добавить или изменить, чтобы это учитывалось?

Comment: Наверное, стоит расшифровать `Моя система координат для пирамиды повернута относительно привычной.`

Comment: Да, я прикрепила картинку к вопросу.

Comment: Можно применить к проверяемым точка аффинное преобразование, которое переводит  пирамиду в тот вид, который Вы описали.

Comment: Тут есть некоторое усложнение. Оно состоит в некотором углублении в задачу: поворот системы координат пирамиды был произведен с помощью трех последовательных применений кватернионов поворота.

Comment: Плюс нужно добавить все же проверку, что точки и пирамида находятся по одну сторону от вершины эллипса. Иначе получается, что попадают лишние задние точки.

Comment: В не повернутой системе координат, как я поняла, для этой проверки подойдет условие, что Pz>=Cz. Тогда все работает, но остается учет поворота.

Comment: Произведение трёх последовательных кватернионов поворота эквивалентно некой матрице афф. преобразования. Может быть, у вас вообще есть финальное представление пирамиды через вершину, направляющий вектор  (в центр основания) и ещё пара параметров?

Comment: Я представила кватернион поворота как матрицу. Пирамида у меня получилась из 4 векторов, проведенных из C и повернутых с помощью кватерниона. Я просто вычислила углы отклонения phi1 и phi2. Но известно, что центр этой пирамиды совпадает с повернутой осью OZ.

Comment: Если у вас есть векторы-рёбра, то можете использовать альтернативу - все смешанные произведения троек (ребро-следующееребро-(P-C)) должны быть положительны (вычислений будет побольше). Однако надо сказать, что вопрос был слишком изменён, на изначальный ответ уже есть.

Comment: Да, я думала, что тут легче будет. Но я не совсем поняла про смешанные произведения троек.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5  Одинаковые знаки говорят о том, что точка находится по одну сторону от всех граней (это невозможно, если она снаружи)

Comment: Кажется, я нашла решение. Достаточно было все точки эллипса и вершину пирамиды с помощью кватерниона повернуть обратно, чтобы все было относительно обычной системы координат. И условия применять уже к таким изменениям. У меня все заработало.